# How to connect to MS SQL Server Express in JetBrains DataGrip?

Tags: sql-server, intellij-idea, jdbc, connection-string, datagrip

I'm trying to set up new tool from `JetBrains`: `DataGrip` to work with my local install of `MS SQL Server 2014 Express`. I spent some time trying to "convert" ms connection string to jdbc, but no luck. I can connect using `MS SQL Server 2014 management Studio`.

So here is my connection string:

```
"Data Source=MyPCName\MySQLInstanceName;Initial Catalog=MyDataBaseNameA3D;Integrated Security=True;"
```

My best guess was based on msdn example:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]
```

[MSDN: Connecting to SQL Server with the JDBC Driver. Building the Connection URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
jdbc:sqlserver://MyPCName\MySQLInstanceName:1433;databaseName=MyDataBaseNameA3D;integratedSecurity=true;
```

Has anyone resolved such issue and maybe can walk me through setup steps?

Otherwise I'm just going to drop this tool. I've wasted enough time on something that should be very simplistic.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

DataGrip has pre-defined jdbc url templates for each jdbc driver. For MS SQL Server it has two drivers:

- SQL Server (Microsoft driver) with the template url connection string: `jdbc:sqlserver://host:port;databaseName=<your db name>`
- SQL Server (jTDS driver) with the template url connection string: `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://host:port/<your db name>`

The name of the database is optional in both cases. These url template are also filled automatically if you set corresponding connection parameters. [Since DataGrip 2016](http://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2016/03/11/datagrip-2016-1-is-open/) completion is also possible when filling the connection settings:
[image: DB connection setting]

Could be that your url is correct but you are getting tcp connection errors. In such case please make sure that **if** you are connecting via TCP port, SQL Server is [**configured to accept remote connections**](http://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/#11) on the specified ip address and [**listens for tcp connections on the specified port**](http://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/#12) number (or see [SQL Server documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx)).

If you are connecting via **named instance**, please make sure to **specify instance name** in the connection settings and omit specifying the port (if it is an "express" version of Sql Server, the instance name could be `SQLEXPRESS`).

**UPD:** see also [*Connecting DataGrip to MS SQL Server*](https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2016/06/21/connecting-datagrip-to-ms-sql-server/) tutorial on DataGrip blog.

Comment: Thanks Andrey! Ones enabled TCP/IP protocol in Sql Server Configuration Manager, everything went smoothly!

Comment: I had to activate the service called _SQLBrowser_ as mentioned in the first link provided. Thanks !

Comment: Thank you, this article https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2016/06/21/connecting-datagrip-to-ms-sql-server/ helped me to fix the problem

Comment: I just wasted lot of time and then found your post and it is correct: with jTds it works instantly.